# the main difference between using sentinel-hub API and free STAC API for getting to sentinel 2 images

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel-hub, stac

I'm a bit confused. What is the main difference between using the Sentinel Hub API and the free STAC API for downloading Sentinel-2 satellite images? Are there any advantages to using the paid Sentinel Hub since booth are getting they data from same open source https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-2/ ?

Comment: Deleting and re-posting an *opinion-based* question with different wording will not result in your desired discussion, but it might cause SE anti-spam defenses to block your account.

Answer (score 1):

If you just look at accessing sentinel-2 data there there doesn't seem to be much difference. But sentinel-hub is much more than just downloading data. It has cloud processing engine for processing of petabytes of satellite data, and considered as a cloud processing solution.

Moreover, you can see the large number of API support from Sentinel-Hub, which allows users to programmatically process satellite data and integrate it into their own applications.

[image: APIs in Sentinel-Hub]

In addition to Copernicus data, they have wide range of satellite data offering. See the list below. And you could bring your own data, and scripts, to process those datasets.

[image: Data in sentinel-hub]

I'd love to hear what community has to say, because there is more to it.